# error con itextSharp ver 5.5.10 al Extraer Imagen de una pagina en particular PDF

Tags: c#, imagen, itextsharp

he tratado de implementar parte de este codigo en mi aplicacion [extract image from pdf](http://Extract%20Image%20from%20a%20particular%20page%20in%20PDF) descargue el itextsharp 5.5.10 pero en la linea de codigo

```
new   Matrix(float.Parse(width), float.Parse(height)
```

sale error corrijo ese error utilizando la version 5.2 de itextsharp pueden saber porque resulta esto?

El error es el siguiente:

> no se puede convertir de 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.Matrix' a
>   'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.GraphicsState'

Comment: ¿Qué error da? Lo puedes poner editando la pregunta.

Comment: no se puede convertir de 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.Matrix' a 'iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser.GraphicsState'

Comment: Mira estas dos entradas: A. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5646148/5587982 B. http://stackoverflow.com/q/10689382/5587982 Si sigue sin funcionar pon el código que estás usando editando tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resulta porque antes el método en ImageRenderInfo.cs era:

```
    public static ImageRenderInfo CreateForXObject(Matrix ctm, PdfIndirectReference refi, PdfDictionary colorSpaceDictionary)
    {
        return new ImageRenderInfo(ctm, refi, colorSpaceDictionary);        
    }
```

Y ahora:

```
    public static ImageRenderInfo CreateForXObject(GraphicsState gs, PdfIndirectReference refi, PdfDictionary colorSpaceDictionary)
    {
        return new ImageRenderInfo(gs, refi, colorSpaceDictionary);
    }
```

Así que el primer parámetro del método ya no es `Matrix`, en la nueva versión es `GraphicsState`.

Si actualizas iTextSharp tendrás que implementar otro código.